# How do I know my laptop is 64-bit compatible?

Tags: laptop, 64-bit, operating-systems, compatibility

I recently plan to buy a new laptop to run a 64-bit OS, but a friend told me that my current laptop is already 64-bit.

How can I verify if my laptop is ready to load a 64-bit OS or not?

Here is the result from CPU-Z:

[image: cpu-z result]

Answer (score 10):

Find out what kind of processor it uses. If it's a 64-bit processor you should be all set. I think anything more recent than a Core 2 on the Intel side is 64-bit and AMD's 64-bit processors usually have a "64" in their name. These are not guaranteed rules, however, so you should always do your homework to be safe.

**edit:** Yes, the T5600 is 64-bit. You see under "Instructions" where it says "EM64T"? That indicates its a 64-bit chip.

Comment: All Intel Core 2 processors are 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the registry:

1. open regedit.exe
2. navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0`
3. Look at the value called `Identifier` to find the processor type

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from the intel site:

Intel® EM64T requires a computer system with a processor, chipset, BIOS, operating system, device drivers and applications enabled for Intel EM64T. Processor will not operate (including 32-bit operation) without an Intel EM64T-enabled BIOS. Performance will vary depending on your hardware and software configurations. See http://www.intel.com/info/em64t for more information including details on which processors support Intel® EM64T or consult with your system vendor for more information.

So yes it is 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have a little app (tied to our own little 64bit os) that tells you the processor name and the type x86(32bit) or x64(64bit) [here](http://www.menuetos.be/beta/CheckCPU.exe) (6Kb download)

It just calls CPUID and checks if long mode is available. (CPUID.80000001H:EDX[Bit 29])

Some C++ code:

```
//Detect if long mode is available by checking bit 29 in EDX when calling 
//CPUID Extended Processor Info and Feature Bits.
int results[4];//eax, ebx, ecx & edx
BOOL 64bit;
__cpuid(results,0x80000001);
if(results[3]&29) 64bit=TRUE; else 64bit=FALSE;
```

Comment: hmm, your tool doesn't seem to work it say x86 it might guess from the OS I currently run on (Windows XP 32bit)