# Running 64-bit Windows 7 on a laptop that came with a 32-bit windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I know my laptop is 64-bit compatible?](https://superuser.com/questions/134645/how-do-i-know-my-laptop-is-64-bit-compatible)

Is it fine to run Windows 7 Home Preminum 64-bit Operating System on a laptop which actually came with Windows 7 Professional 32-bit Operating System? Will there be any problem? Is it even possible? How can I check and confirm whether my hardware is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: It depends on your CPU.  Look up the CPU spec sheet on the manufacturer's website, and it will indicate if it's 64-bit compatible (almost all modern ones are).  Just an FYI, you will have to do a complete re-installation of Windows.

Comment: @Breakthrough FYI, I am not a kid to be unaware of that.

Comment: I mentioned that because you *can* switch between the various Windows editions without reinstalling, but switching between 32 and 64-bit editions requires a re-install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SKUs arn't generally locked to hardware types so switching from 7 pro to 7 home should be doable.

Switching from 32 to 64 bit ... depends on the system. *Most* systems in the last 7 years or so *should* be x64 compatible - you can check this with a tool like cpu-z which gives processor information - it should have a processor flag like AMD64 or EMT64 to be able to run a 64 bit OS. If it does, it should be able to run a 64 bit OS with no issue

[image]

This would be an example of a system that came with a 32 bit OS, where i could install a 64 bit OS - in this case XP to windows 7. Assuming your other hardware is supported, it should not be a problem to switch from 64 bit to 32 bit, or vice versa.

While you'd want to check if your OEM has 64 bit drivers, chances are that what you want would work quite easily.

Comment: He is not asking that..

Comment: Actually, in effect that IS what he's asking - basically *any* laptop made in the last 5-6 years would do what he's asking. Without further details, telling him *how* to check, and pointing out driver support as the only issue pretty much answers his question

Comment: Just like to add that if OP visits the manufacturer's website, they often provide a list of which products are supported in the 64-bit environment and will,therefore, have official drivers available.

Comment: Now, its perfect. When I commented, it was just one line answer to explain nothing..